# Set model state with React Hooks in form inputs

Tags: reactjs, forms, setstate, react-hooks

How do I change the state of a model using the built-in `setState()` function in React Hooks for form inputs?

For example how do bind `setFirstName()` with `onChange` in the input field?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Demo = () => {
   const [ firstName, setFirstName ] = useState('');

   return (
     <div>
       <form>
        <input className="input" name="firstname" value={firstName} 
         //what do i put in onChange here?
          onChange=? />
        </form>
     </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const App = () => {

   //Initialize to empty string
   const [ firstName, setFirstName ] = useState("");

   const handleSubmit = () => {
      //You should be able console log firstName here
      console.log(firstName)
   }

   return (
     <div>
       <form>
        <input className="input" name="firstname" value={firstName} 
          onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
       </form>
     </div>

    );
}
```

Comment: react hooks are now in v16.8: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html